# Room database insert function kotlinx.coroutines.JobCancellationException

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I've got some simple code like this:

**PlansDao**

```
@Dao
interface PlansDao {

    @Insert(entity = PlanDbo::class)
    suspend fun insertPlan(planDbo: PlanDbo): Long

}
```

**Repository**

```
class PlansRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val plansDao: PlansDao
) : PlansRepository {
    override suspend fun writePlan(plan: PlanDbo) {
        Log.d("MAIN_TAG", "start to plansDao.insertPlan(plan): $plan")
        plansDao.insertPlan(plan)
        Log.d("MAIN_TAG", "end of plansDao.insertPlan(plan): $plan")
    }
}
```

**PlanDbo**

```
@Entity(tableName = "plans")
data class PlanDbo(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Long = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name") val name: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "start_time") val startTime: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "end_time") val endTime: String
)
```

As you can see, there are two log function lines, the thing is when i call `repository.writePlan(plan)` (it is called in viewModelScope) the first log message (start of the inserting) shows, but the second one (end of the inserting) never does. Also, the plan object actually appears in the database but sometimes not.

I also tryed this kind of thing with simple DELETE query and the DELETE works completely fine.

What should I do to fix the never-ending insert function?

**UPDATE**
Actually, when I contained plansDao.insertPlan(plan) in try-catch block I got this: `W/System.err: kotlinx.coroutines.JobCancellationException: Job was cancelled;` and I still can't imagine why it could happen

Comment: Have you tried to contain "plansDao.insertPlan(plan)" in the try-catch block and check if there any Exception occurs?

Comment: @VindIskald thanks! That made the caule of this problem more clear but I still can't find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got an answer. It was about viewModelScope. The thing is that I have a screen for adding plans and it has it's own viewModel and when I pressed a button, a `viewModelScope.launch{ plansRepository.writePlan(plan) }` was called and immediately screen closed.
So the viewModel 'died' and it's scope did also. That's why the coroutine was canceled

The problem was solved by replacing viewModelScope by MainScope but I'm not sure that it is the best scope for this situation

Comment: I guess it's better if ViewModel would notify Fragment about completion of saving plan into room by liveData/flow/interface (depending of your current architecture) so after that it initiates transition to another Fragment (closes).

Answer (score 0):

In my case error happened, because of mistake with `LifecycleOwner`. I took owner from my `Dialog`, not from `Fragment`. And when a dialog was closed I got an exception.

`owner` - here are from `convertDialog`, not from `MyFragment`, be carefull!

```kotlin
MyFragment : Fragment() {

    ...

    convertDialog.apply {
        onPositiveClick {
            viewModel.convert().collect(owner = this) { connector.convertNote() }
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

Fix my problem:

```
viewModel.convert().collect(owner = this@MyFragment) { connector.convertNote() }
```